# Link matlab script to a qt creator gui

Tags: matlab, qt-creator

I try to develop a `qt` gui that asks the user to enter some parameters and integrate those parameters into a matlab script. Finally execute the matlab script from qt. Is that possible???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a C++ interface to Matlab:

http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/calling-matlab-engine-from-c-c-and-fortran-programs.html

I guess that would be a possibility.

Of course you can also run start Matlab with a `system` call and specify the script/function to run.

Comment: Yes i know that but i want that the script to run will get the variable declaration fro the qt gui.

Comment: Well, then use the C++ interface. You can first send your variable-declarations either via `engPutVariable` or `engEvalString` and run the script afterwards.